# Data Binding between two TextBoxes in different windows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a program that changes the name in a TextBox when check or unckeck a Checkbox. I want to replicate this Textbox in a different window. I thought with Data Mining in the xaml would be possible, but the name only appears in one window. Second window window does´t recieve the data. I show you the code of the two windows.
 Can you help me? Thankss

Window 1.cs---

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    Texto prueba = new Texto("Carlos");


    public static string s;
    public Window1()
    {
       InitializeComponent( );
      // Fill initial person fields
       this.textBox1.Text = prueba.Name;          

    }


    private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        prueba.Name="Carlos";
        textBox1.DataContext = prueba;
        textBox1.Text = prueba.Name;
    }

    private void checkBox1_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        prueba.Name = "Luis";
        textBox1.DataContext = prueba;
        textBox1.Text = prueba.Name;
    }
}

 public class Texto
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }

     public Texto( ) {}
     public Texto(string name) 
     {
       this.name = name;
     }

}


}
```

window1 xaml-------

```
     <Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,118,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox1_Checked" Unchecked="checkBox1_UnChecked" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,140,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

window2 cs-----

```
 namespace WpfApplication1
 {

   public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 nueva = new Window1();
        nueva.Show();
    }
 }


}
```

window2 xaml--------

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,121,0,0" Name="button1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <TextBox DataContext="prueba" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,84,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to pass a reference to either the first window or the object that you're updating the text property on to the second window, it's DataContext property will do for that, you can then bind the second windows controls to it.

In this demo application I've created a MainWindow and a second window (Window1), the application starts in Main window like this.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string TestString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestStringProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register("TestString", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // setup the test string.
        TestString = "this is a test.";

        // Create the second window and pass this window as it's data context.
        Window1 newWindow = new Window1()
        {
            DataContext = this
        };
        newWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml** - Take note of the DataContext line in the Window declaration.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        >
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TestString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="91,84,185,189" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now for Window1 the code behind is just an empty default window class so I won't post it but the xaml is.

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: As an extra, if you're new to dependency properties it can look daunting, this will work just as well if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the event when you change the TestString property.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the DataContext explicitly, or only via another Binding. Your

```
<TextBox DataContext="prueba"
```

does nothing helpful. DataContext will be inherited as long as it is not overwritten. Don't set it explicitly. It should be enought to set it once on both windows.

Create your data object in your MainWindow

```
Texto prueba = new Texto("Carlos");
Window1 nueva = new Window1();
nueva.DataContext = prueba;
nueva.Show();
```

and remove all the other DataContext assignments.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things wrong here, but I can probably give you a quick solution to fix your problem.  First off your DataContext on window 2 isn't working properly, you can set it exclusively in your code right before you show window1...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 nueva = new Window1();
    this.DataContext = nueva.prueba;
    nueva.Show();
}
```

Next you have to fire INotifyPropertyChanged in your Texto class...

```
public class Texto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set 
        { 
            this.name = value; 
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

     public Texto( ) {}
     public Texto(string name) 
     {
        this.name = name;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both textboxes share a common datacontext it will "just work" without any code required...